# Selenium Noise removal

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I have extracted some details from a website, it is shown in the console of selenium. It contains some extra things that I don't require. Is the removal of those things can be done manually or am I missing some concept????

here is the part of code:
public class selenium {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int i=1;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "F:\\Downloads\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.21.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/");
    WebElement text=driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox"));
    text.sendKeys("Samsung Phones");
    text.submit();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    while(i==1)
    {
    //List<WebElement> links=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".a-size-base.s-inline.s-access-title.a-text-normal")); 
List<WebElement>links=driver.findElements(By.partialLinkText("Samsung"));
    System.out.println(links.size());
    for(WebElement link : links)       
    {
        //if(link.getText().contains("Samsung"))
         System.out.println(link.getText());
```

[image: image-data extracted]

problems:

1. On searching Samsung phones, I got data also for Samsung cover.
2. For each page of data extracted, a text used for searching "Samsung phones" is also got printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem1:** This can not be avoided. But you can try with the following xpath

```
//ul/li[contains(@class,'s-result-item')]//a/h2[not(contains(.,'cover'))]
```

**Problem2:** Solved by xpath only to the result items as given above. change the following line in your code.

```
List<WebElement>links=driver.findElements(By.partialLinkText("Samsung"));
```

with

```
List<WebElement>links=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul/li[contains(@class,'s-result-item')]//a/h2[not(contains(.,'cover'))]
"));
```

Comment: this selector will not filter element that contains "Cover". it only search searches for "cover" and than will apply not condition on it. As I can see on website some elements have "Cover" in the text and not "cover". So, it will give the wrong count of elements. It will give elements that have text "Cover" present in them. You can try printing it on console.You will find the text containing "Cover". You have to apply ignore case condition on it.

Answer (score 0):

this will get you the exact count of elements (without cover) :

```
//a//h2[not(contains(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),'cover'))]
```

It will ignore all cover elements (it is case insensitive)

use this selector in driver.findElements() and you are done.